# Attention Mechanisms and Alignment Models in Machine Translation

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, attention, machine-translation

From the paper that introduced attention mechanisms ([Bahdanau et al 2014: Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf)), it seems that the *translating* part is the regular RNN/LSTM encoder-decoder and the *aligning* part is the actual attention mechanism (another smaller MLP), used to align words in the input language sentence into the target sentence.

Is that interpretation correct? the so-called attention mechanism **is** the alignment model?

In that case, the attention mechanism is used to  *attend* to certain input words in the source sentence during each iterative prediction of words for the target sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the idea that the original paper promoted.

Note, however, that it is a little bit tricky to use the term alignment. For purposes of the statistical machine translation, it was defined as a meaning correspondence of the source and target words. A [highly cited 2017 study](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W17-3204) shows that the attention might learn very unintuitive alignments which seem totally wrong without any loss of translation quality.